# Putty received data only shows after pressing Enter

Tags: windows, putty, rs232

I am working on an application which pulls data from an RS232-enabled device. I am able to connect to the device using Putty and send queries, however the response is not shown immediately in Putty. I need to keep pressing the Enter key for each character in the response.

Can this be avoided in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Check your [flow control](https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/RS-232_flow_control.html) settings. Perhaps your device does not use the default one in Putty.

`Putty Configuration -> Connection -> Serial -> Flow Control`

Note that some of the options require additional wires which may not be populated in your cable or provided by your serial controller. So, some reading may be necessary.

Comment: I was able to trace the problem to the flow control as you suggested and left only RX, TX and GND connected with Xon/Xoff option, now it works. Thank you for the suggestion.